# How to set all bits of enum flag

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

I wonder a generic way for setting all bits of `enum` flag to 1.
I just would like to have an `enum` which returns for all comparisons, regardless of other enums.

And this code works;

```
[Flags]
public enum SomeRightEnum : uint
{
    CanDoNothing = 0,
    CanDoSomething = 1 << 0,
    CanDoSomethingElse = 1 << 1,
    CanDoYetAnotherThing = 1 << 2,
    ...
    DoEverything = 0xFFFFFFFF 
}
```

But at the  code above since it is uint we set the number of "F"s, it wouldn't work if it was `int`.

So I'll appreciate a generic way of setting all bits of `enum` flag to 1, regardless of the datatype (`i`nt, `int64`, `uint` etc)

Comment: Hmmm.  The intent of enumerations is to describe mutually exclusive options.  You seem to be using them as shorthand for a bunch of bitmasks.

Comment: @AFgone You are using the [Flags] attribute on the enum right?

Comment: @Oli The [Flags] attribute on the enum is designed for this purpose.

Comment: @Bernie White: The Flags attribute is purely cosmetic, you CAN use 'flags' without it.

Comment: @Bernie sure, I edited, just forgat to copy it

Comment: @leppie http://ideone.com/qkc8b

Comment: @Scott: The `ToString` representation is cosmetic. The semantics and behaviors is identical with or without the `Flags` attribute.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Easiest is probably:

```
enum Foo
{
  blah = 1,
  ....
  all = ~0
}
```

For unsigned based enum:

```
enum Foo : uint
{
  blah = 1,
  ....
  all = ~0u;
}
```

Comment: when I try this it says "Constant value '-1' cannot be converted to a 'uint' "

Comment: Just cast it then, eg `unchecked((uint)~0)`

Comment: Can int.MaxValue be used?

Comment: @Vladius: Sure, but why? :D

Comment: @Vladius: int.MaxValue has not set the sign bit (bit 31) its value is hexadecimal 0x7FFFFFFF. So only bits 0 to 30 are set. You can use -1 for signed types but not for unsigned types. Still ~0 is the best.

Comment: ~0 is not good enough as you can't test for it. The combination of all options is not equal to ~0

Comment: It's worth mentioning that whilst this does work here, ~0 is all 1s, even for the values you haven't assigned yet. So you can't use it for int comparison unless you have 31 flags. @realstrategos 's answer below has an accurate shortcut for all = ~(-1 << 4) in which only the bits required are set.

Answer (score 33):

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    None   = 0,
    First  = 1 << 0,
    Second = 1 << 1,
    Third  = 1 << 2,
    Fourth = 1 << 3,
    All = ~(-1 << 4)
}
```

Comment: I like this option even better than my usual `-1` option. I was using an enum to keep track of which tasks were requested and removing the flag when the task was completed. My plan was then to use the result as the exit code. So this helps with the maintenance of the tasks enum.

Comment: I prefer `All = ~(~0 << 4)` because it's a little more clear. Not everyone knows that `-1` is all `1`s.

Comment: `None` shouldn't be `-1` ?!

Comment: Why do you shift -1 by 4 steps?

Comment: @C0DEF52 Im willing to bet he did it to keep the consistency in layout for each value. I do the same for 0 where i set the flag equal to (0 << 0) because it makes everything look nice.

Comment: @C0DEF52 How else would you do it? -1 sets all flags to 1, shifting left 4 means you have all 1's followed by 4 0s, invert that gives you all 4 flags set.

Comment: @Tod yes I understand now but I didn't get it in the past when asked. By the way another way to set All is to unite all other flags: `All = First | Second | Third | Fourth`

Comment: Isn't this 11101111, while it should be 00001111?

Answer (score 8):

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.Everything.HasFlag(Foo.None)); // False
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.Everything.HasFlag(Foo.Baz)); // True
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.Everything.HasFlag(Foo.Hello)); // True
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum Foo : uint
{
    None = 1 << 0,
    Bar = 1 << 1,
    Baz = 1 << 2,
    Qux = 1 << 3,
    Hello = 1 << 4,
    World = 1 << 5,
    Everything = Bar | Baz | Qux | Hello | World
}
```

Was this what you wanted?

Comment: but this is not regardless of other enums, when I  edit or remove enums I have to change also "Everything"

Comment: This is the correct solution. `~0` is not good enough as you can't test for it. The combination of all options is not equal to ~0.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is wondering:
I needed to do the same building a Bindable enumconverter for WPF.
Since I don't know what the values mean in Reflection, I needed to manually been able to switch values (binding them to a checkbox p.e.)
There is a problem setting the value of a Flagged enum to -1 to set all the bits.
If you set it to -1 and you unflag all values it will not result in 0 because all unused bits are not unflagged.
 This is wat worked best for my situation.

```
SomeRightEnum someRightEnum = SomeRightEnum.CanDoNothing;
Type enumType = someRightEnum.GetType();
int newValue = 0;
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<int>().Where(e => e == 1 || e % 2 == 0);
foreach (var value in enumValues)
{
    newValue |= value;
}
Console.WriteLine(newValue);
```

Or if you would want an extension method:

```
public static class FlagExtensions
{
    public static TEnum AllFlags<TEnum>(this TEnum @enum)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(TEnum);
        long newValue = 0;
        var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        foreach (var value in enumValues)
        {
            long v = (long)Convert.ChangeType(value, TypeCode.Int64);
            if(v == 1 || v % 2 == 0)
            {
               newValue |= v; 
            }
        }
        return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType , newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: make it an extension method named `AllFlags` that extends the `enum` system class. then it could be used neatly `enum.AllFlags(typeof(MyEnum))` no ?

Comment: @v.oddou I have updated my answer with a generic extension that returns the (immutable) value. I also removed a bug to omit non-flag values.

Answer (score 0):

I find `All = ~0` more elegant, but to have more transparency starting from **C# 7.0** you can use

binary literals like `0b0101010111` together with digit separators `_` like `0b_0101_0101_11`.

So to set **all flags** for the `Int32` you can chose one of the following possibilities, all of them are the same:

```
All = unchecked((int)0b_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111)
All = unchecked((int)0b_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111)
All = unchecked((int)0b11111111111111111111111111111111)
```